# Better way to Set Background Color with wx.DC

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Right now, I am setting the background colour like this,

`dc.DrawRectangle(0,0,width,height)`

Do you know a better way to set the background color?

http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing now?

Comment: I am hoping for a better way.

Comment: The background colour of what exactly do you need to change?  Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way, which works for most windows, including buttons and other widgets is to call wxWindow::SetBackgroundColour()

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowsetbackgroundcolour

The neat thing is that if you call this on the topmost parent, all the children will automatically inherit the same background colour.  See the link for how exactly this works.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already painting on a `wx.DC` to draw the rest of the window's content then the best way is to set the background brush, and then clear the DC.  Something like this:

```
def OnPaint(self, event):
    dc= wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(someColour))
    dc.Clear()
    # other drawing stuff...
```

If you are setting the colour with the window's `SetBackgroundColour` method, then you can use that instead of some fixed colour value, like this:

```
def OnPaint(self, event):
    dc= wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour()))
    dc.Clear()
    # other drawing stuff...
```

Comment: what does dc.Clear() do?

Comment: OP wants to set the color of a particular area of background, not the entire background. Therefore he uses dc.DrawRectangle(0,0,width,height). He'd like to know if it is the only  (and best) way

Comment: `dc.Clear` fills the whole DC with the background brush, which is what the OP is implying he wants to do in the main question: "...Set Background Color with wx.DC", assuming the width and height are the size of the DC.  His approach is the common newbie method to clear the DC, using `dc.Clear` is the better way he is looking for.